# How to execute bash (in script) with own .bash_logout file?

Tags: bash, exec, subshell, logout

I want to execute bash in subshell and when user exits from subshell, I want to execute some other commands (like for saving logs to file).

Something like this:

### run.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash 

function save_information_to_file()
{
    echo "${date} ${time} new bash subshell ended !"
}
# Some commands etc.

env PS1='SubShell:' bash --rcfile /home/username/.bashrc

if [ user_logout_from_subshell ]
then 
     save_information_to_file()
fi;
```

### Executed :

```
user: ./run.sh
2016-08-12 14:55:13 new bash subshell started...
SubShell: echo "wow..."
wow... 
SubShell: pwd
/home/username
SubShell: cat user.log
2016-08-11 17:54:32 bash started
2016-08-11 17:56:14 bash ended
2016-08-11 18:23:18 bash started
2016-08-11 18:39:30 bash ended
SubShell: exit
exit
2016-08-12 14:59:41 new bash subshell ended !
user:
```

How to run bash with path to file that have to be executed on exit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first thought was .bash_logout too, but that only works for login shells.  The most straightforward method, which works for both login and non-login shells, is setting a trap on exit.  It works like this:

trap "your_commands_go_here" EXIT

For example,

`$ bash
$ trap "echo goodbye cruel world!" EXIT
$ exit
exit
goodbye cruel world!`

Comment: BTW, this was the question that finally made me join U&L!

Answer (score 4):

You don't need any special tricks. This is enough:

```
#!/bin/bash 

env PS1='SubShell:' bash --rcfile /home/username/.bashrc

echo Subshell exited. Now doing something...
```

The subshell will run in the main terminal. The main script will wait for it to finish without any extra commands.

(I don't know how you can set `PS1` from above the shell. I guess it gets overwritten at the subshell Bash startup.)

Comment: My mistake - PS1 is set in rcfile :)

Answer (score 3):

There is a file in home directory of each user named .bash_logout, try to insert the commands you want in it.

Comment: `.bash_logout` only executes when a login shell exits. He's not creating a login shell.

Answer (score 0):

There is the possibility that .bash_logout does not already exist in your home directory. I've run into this in the past. If this is the case, just vi/vim and create your own .bash_logout file in your home directory and this should do the trick.